Can't connect to mariadb from kubernetes cluster
Here is the server.py file (not complete yet, but no errors in syntax):
import jwt, datetime, os
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

server = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL(server)

#config
server.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_HOST")
server.config["MYSQL_USER"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_USER")
server.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_PASSWORD")
server.config["MYSQL_DB"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_DB")
server.config["MYSQL_PORT"] = int(os.environ.get("MYSQL_PORT"))


@server.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    auth = request.authorization
    if not auth:
        return "missing credentials", 401

    #Check db for username and password
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    res = cur.execute(
            "SELECT email, password FROM user WHERE email=%s", (auth.username,)
    )

    if res>0:
        user_row = cursor.fetchone()
        email = user_row[0]
        password = user_row[1]

        if auth.username != email or auth.password != password:
            return "Invalid credentials", 401
        else:
            return createJWT(auth.username, os.environ.get("JWT_SECRET"), True)
    else:
        return "Invalid credentials", 401

@server.route("/validate", methods=["POST"])
def validate():
    encoded_jwt = request.headers["Authorization"]

    if not encoded_jwt:
        return "Missing credentials", 401

    encoded_jwt = encoded_jwt.split()[1]

    try:
        decoded = jwt.decode(
                encoded_jwt, os.environ.get("JWT_SECRET"), algorithm=["HS256"]
                )
    except:
        return "Not Authorised", 403

    return decoded, 200


def createJWT(username, secret, authz):
    return jwt.encode(
        {
            "username": username,
            "exp": datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.datetime.utc)
            + datetime.timedelta(days = 1),
            "iat": datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            "admin":authz,


        },
        secret,
        algorithm="HS256"
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)

init.sql file so credentials are clear:
create user 'auth_user'@'%' identified by 'aauth123';

create database auth;
grant all privileges on auth.* to 'auth_user'@'%';
flush privileges;

use auth;

create table user (
    id int auto_increment primary key not null,
    email varchar(50) not null unique,
    password varchar(255) not null
);

insert into user (email, password) values ('kuros@email.com', '123456');

here is the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests \
    build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev pkg-config \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file and install Python dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

# Copy the entire application code
COPY . /app

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 5000

# Command to run the application
CMD ["python3", "server.py"]

here are the config files for kubernetes:
auth-deploy.yaml:
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth
  labels:
    app: auth

spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 3

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: auth
        image: kuriousking/auth
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: auth-configmap
          - secretRef:
              name: auth-secret

configmap.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: auth-configmap
data:
  MYSQL_HOST: host.minikube.internal
  MYSQL_USER: auth_user
  MYSQL_DB: auth
  MYSQL_PORT: "3306"

secret.yaml:
apiVersion: v1

kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: auth-secret

stringData:
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: Aauth123
  JWT_SECRET: sarcasm

type: Opaque

service.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  type: ClusterIP 
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      protocol: TCP

the /etc/hosts file:
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   alien

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

#kubecontext on localhost and container
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal

#for docker and kubernetes
127.0.0.1 mp3converter.com

127.0.0.1 rabbitmq-manager.com

the error:
◰venv  ~/c/s/s/p/s/auth  curl -X POST http://10.107.187.61:5000/login -u kuros@email.com:123456
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>

The cluster logs:
◰venv  ~/c/s/s/p/s/auth  kubectl logs auth-666f84cb7b-hznx6      Saturday 12 October 2024 01:30:49 AM
 * Serving Flask app 'server'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://10.244.0.166:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2024-10-11 20:00:48,068] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/app/server.py", line 23, in login
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 109, in connection
    ctx.mysql_db = self.connect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 97, in connect
    return MySQLdb.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 195, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host.minikube.internal' (115)")
10.244.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2024 20:00:48] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -

when I try to hit the domain by name ping works and I get a response but not when I use curl:
 ◰venv  ~/c/s/s/p/s/auth  ping rabbitmq-manager.com       37.7s  Saturday 12 October 2024 01:41:42 AM
PING rabbitmq-manager.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mp3converter.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from mp3converter.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from mp3converter.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
64 bytes from mp3converter.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
^C
--- rabbitmq-manager.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3062ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.043/0.066/0.077/0.013 ms

curl:
    !  ◰venv  ~/c/s/s/p/s/a/manifests  curl -X POST http://mp3converter.com/login -u kuros@email.com:'123456'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mp3converter.com port 80 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I am following this tutorial from freecodecamp: https://youtu.be/hmkF77F9TLw?si=w5UegdSmtjIUypkr
here is his code (my problem is in the auth cluster only): https://github.com/kantancoding/microservices-python/tree/main/src/auth
os info: I am running debian 12 and I can access mariadb locally but not via the application
let me know if you need more info, could really use some help here, thanks a lot
Note: mariadb is running in background on my laptop locally not as a pod or container

I do not see mariadb deployed anywhere

its running as a systemd service locally, I mean this is mysql in the code, but it should work the same with mariadb, right? or I have to make changes?
I am kinda new to using kubernetes#

Socket error 115 (errno: 115 at the end of the error message) means operation in progress. This indicates that the tcp handshake did not complete before your client started another operation. This is not going to be a programming issue, but a network one. Perhaps you have a firewall or anti virus app blocking the connection or mariadb is not configured to accept remote connections.

nope, no firewall at all,  I made an update to the post that mariadb is running locally and I don't have any anti virus or firewall, so how is that happening and not to mention the dns in hosts file aren't working either (atleast for curl)
